# How to create a solid gauge chart using amcharts with custom data configuration?

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I have a sample AmCharts solid gauge charts and I want to render it using the values from the Category and Size textboxes. For example , the textarea will have this JSON data ,

```
[
{
      "Country":"Malaysia",
      "Size":260,
      "State":"Selangor",
      "Population":450
   },
   {
      "Country":"England",
      "Size":140,
      "State":"Liverpool",
      "Population":100
   },
   {
      "Country":"China",
      "Size":250,
      "State":"Beijing",
      "Population":200
   },
   {
      "Country":"South Korea",
      "Size":360,
      "State":"Seoul",
      "Population":300
   }
]
```

Then I set Category to be Country , so it loads 4 axes with 4 labels.

Then I set Size to be Population , so it loads the endValue(startValue starts from 0 right?) to be that. And the percentage is derived from maxValue * 1.2.

My main question is , How do I render a gauge chart using AmCharts with custom data configuration? dataProvider does not seem to work here like it does in serial charts.

**Codepen link** : https://codepen.io/ariff20/pen/WaKJRV

Comment: Correct, `dataProvider` does not exist in gauge charts. You need to change your approach so that you dynamically convert your data into axes and arrow values. Just map them into the appropriate objects instead of creating a dataProvider-style array.

Comment: @xorspark  map them into the "appropriate" objects?  What is considered an appropriate object for this case?

Comment: The corresponding objects in the makeChart call, of course. You want an axis for each country? array.map your data and return an array of axes. Same goes for labels and bands. Instead of the static setup you have, generate them dynamically from your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating further on my comment - since `dataProvider` does not exist in a gauge chart, you can remap your data and create the appropriate properties/arrays in your config instead of trying to set them manually in your codepen. For instance, your bands can be generated like so:

```
  var colors = ["#84b761", "#fdd400", "#cc4748", "#67b7dc"]; //assuming 4 bands/colors - adjust as needed
  var bands = mappedData.reduce(function(acc, d, idx) {
    acc.push({
      color: "#eee",
      startValue: 0,
      endValue: d.target,
      radius: 100 - 20 * idx + "%",
      innerRadius: 85 - 20 * idx + "%"
    });
    acc.push({
      color: colors[idx],
      startValue: 0,
      endValue: d.value,
      radius: 100 - 20 * idx + "%",
      innerRadius: 85 - 20 * idx + "%",
      balloonText: parseFloat(d.value / d.target * 100).toFixed(2)
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Labels can be generated in a similar manner:

```
  var labels = mappedData.map(function(d, idx) {
    return {
      text: d.name,
      x: "49%",
      y: 6 + 9 * idx + "%",
      size: 15,
      bold: true,
      color: colors[idx],
      align: "right"
    };
  });
```

Once generated, simply fill in the blanks in your setting template and pass it into your makeChart call, clearing any previous instances first:

```
var chart; //global ref to clear the chart
function changeData() {
  // ... omitted
  var setting = {
    type: "gauge",
    theme: "light",
    axes: [
      {
        axisAlpha: 1,
        tickAlpha: 1,
        labelsEnabled: true,
        startValue: 0,
        endValue: Math.max.apply(
          Math,
          mappedData.map(function(o) {
            return o.target;
          })
        ),
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 270,
        bands: bands
      }
    ],
    allLabels: labels,
    export: {
      enabled: true
    }
  };
  if (chart) {
    chart.clear();
    chart = null;
  }
  chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", setting);
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/8599e1375ceb9a3f708ecf3a0a9120a7/)

Comment: So this only works for a maximum of 5 bands? What if I have more than that? The labels overlaps for the 6th band and the bands also go haywire. Awesome solution though.

Comment: You'll have to figure out the right settings (radius, innerRadius, label font sizes, etc) and possibly tweak your div CSS to accommodate  more than 5 bands. I didn't test this beyond your sample data.

Comment: Okay noted. So the radius cannot be more than 100% or else the chart will be too large and can't reach 0% right or else the final bar wont show. As for innerRadius ,  I believe it's also on a decreasing path until the final data right?

Comment: Pretty much. Of course you can only go so far band/axis-wise before you can't fit everything into one chart. You might want to consider introducing a limit on how many bands you can comfortably render in a single div and/or possibly splitting your data across multiple charts.

Comment: Cool. I figured out a way to render the bands based on the data with the right radius,innerRadius. But the labels are still not formatted right. Maybe you could have a look?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005647/how-to-set-the-font-size-and-y-position-of-the-text-to-be-aligned-with-the-bands